# Inheritance issue : Results are different on creating same class object

Tags: java

Case 1:
In the below example if i call a.i it is printing 10 as answer. But  A a = new B(); isn"t this like object of b is getting created so value 20 should be printed instead of 10.

```
class A
{
    int i = 10;
}

class B extends A
{
    int i = 20;
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new B();
        System.out.println(a.i);
    }
}
```

Case 2:
    Also if i create the same program as above using methods inside classes instead of printing variable values as in above case then result is different :

```
class A{

    void test(){
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}

    class B extends A{
        void test(){
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                A a=new B();
                System.out.println(a.test);
    }
```

Now in this case hi is printed instead of hello , so why is the behavior different when i try to print variable value and when using methods? Overiding happens between the methods only and not with variables?

Comment: Fields are not polymorphic.

Comment: I think this is called static binding

Comment: `B.i` is shadowed by `A.i` and not overriden like you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

In Java only methods can be [overriden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html), not instance variables.

When you declare a field with the same name as an existing field in a superclass, the new field hides the existing field. The existing field from the superclass is still present in the subclass, and can even be used

Check these -

Java Tutorial - [Hiding Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.htmlhttp://)

JLS Example - [Hiding of instance fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e10217)

Comment: seems you getting hard time setting hyperlink on references :) .. anyways nice answer

Comment: :) i got it right in 2-3 tries..

Answer (score 2):

Because what you have in the first example has nothing to do with polymorphism as fields read are not dynamically dispatched.

What you have however is a name shadowing, so `i` in the statement `A.i` refers to the field declared in `A` and `B.i` is invisible at this point.